# How do I make Openshift to use Express 4, instead of its installed Express 3?

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

I developed my Nodejs Express app locally using Express 4 and it works as expected on my computer. I then git the whole app up to Openshift. When I try to run it Openshift returns"503 Service Unavailable".  If I ssh into my base Node cartridge and do "express -V" it returns version 3.2.5. I get the same version 3.2.5 if I go into my app folder at app-root/repo and run "express -V".

So clearly my Express 4 which was included in the git upload in my app's node_modules is not being used. What is the solution to use Express 4 as required by my app?

Ideas are- remove Openshift's version of Express 3, force Openshift to use my Express 4 in my app area, upgrade Openshift's Express 3 to Express 4. I cannot figure out how to do any of those and I have researched this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to troubleshoot:

- ssh into your cartridge
- cd into the app-root/repo directory
- run `grep version ./node_modules/express/package.json`
- you should see a version based on your `package.json` dependency
- verify your package.json has a `scripts` section containing a `start` command that just runs your app with something like `node ./server.js` (server.js being whatever file you coded your main app start script in). You don't need the `express` command line program to launch an express server. It's for setting up new project boilerplate and other ancillary tasks.
- To see the version of express running within your app, you can add this code to your `server.js` (or equivalent) file: `console.log(require("express/package").version);`

Comment: I had  "express": "~4.0.0"  but maybe that is not pushy enough. I will make it exact,  "express": "=4.9.0",  try it, and get back.

Comment: Unfortunately no change. Apparently when the Node cartridge starts up it is tied to the Openshift Express version that was installed outside the app project folder. It still publishes a version of 3.2.5 and the app fails to start. I again have verified that the app still runs on my local computer as intended.

There has be a way to update the Openshift version of Express to the latest but I have found no docs on it, or tech talk about it.  Any help along these lines?

Comment: following your instructions I do see-    "version": "4.12.0",

So my project is built using Express 4 and when run locally it runs correctly. But when I am running the app on openshift it appears that Node starts up the Openshift Express 3 outside of the app folder, not using my Express 4.  

Is there a Javascript/Express command that can be run WITHIN the running app to display the version of Express that is active ?  I don't mean grep the package.json, that only tells me Express 4 code is in my app area. I want the running  Express to tell me who he is, by his version no.

Comment: I doubt the express3 that is installed is actually running. Express doesn't run. node runs. your code runs and requires express and that will use the one in your app's node_modules folder. I added code above you can use to confirm which version is actually running within your app.

Comment: That line of code you just provided was hugely helpful. You are absolutely right, Express 3 is being ignored. This information takes this "issue" out of the picture. I wish I could up-vote you somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this project to know how to integrate openshift with express4
Its a simple example .

https://github.com/master-atul/openshift-express4

Answer (score 1):

try this

rhc ssh
cd app-root/repo
npm start

also edit the ./bin/www

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || '8080'); 
var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
        if (typeof ip === "undefined") {
            //  Log errors on OpenShift but continue w/ 127.0.0.1 - this
            //  allows us to run/test the app locally.
            console.warn('No OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP var, using 127.0.0.1');
            ip = "127.0.0.1";
        };
//app.set('ip', port);  
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, ip);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can follow step:

1. copy all content `bin/www` and replace all content in file `server.js`:
2. Change some content at `server.js`:

from

```
`var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');`
```

to

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || '3000');
```

Add line:

```
var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
```

from

```
server.listen(port);
```

to

```
server.listen(port, ip);
```

3. Add more to package.json

from

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/www"
},
```

to

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
},
```

Add line:

```
"main": "server.js",
```

4. Use `npm install --save module-name` for `npm install`
5. create file .gitignore with content:

   `node_modules`
6. on local run `node server.js` to start server with address localhost:3000
7. upload to openshift:

   `git add .`
   `git commit -m "First update new server version"`
   `git push`
8. Browser: `domain-appname.rhcloud.com`

Comment: That is the right answer, just with a little more step:
At start of bin/www, in the line `var app = require('../app');` just remove one point to address to the right path when the script is executed from root path on `server.js` -> `var app = require('./app');`